# Sqoop Invalid connection URL SQL Server

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hadoop2

When I try to run sqoop I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connection URL url jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:{port}
```

My command is:

```
sqoop list-databases \
--connect jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:{port} --username abc --password xyz
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the valid SQLserver URL: `jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx:3464;databaseName=testing`

your command should use `hostname` or `IP` in JDBC string NOT username,
you can get `hostname` of your computer from this command: `hostname -f` or use `hostname -i` for `IP`

```
sqoop list-databases \
--driver com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver \
--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:{port}' \
--username abc \
--password xyz
```

OR

```
sqoop list-databases 
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://ML-xyz:1433;username=abc;password=abc"
```

[example is here:](https://github.com/hortonworks/hadoop-tutorials/blob/master/Community/T04_Import_from_Microsoft_SQL_Server_into_the_Hortonworks_Sandbox_using_Sqoop.md)

```
sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.56.1:1433 --username hadoop --password hadoop1
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I did have the host there, unfortunately, still got that error.

Comment: try to single quote `'` the jdbc string

Comment: Tried with no luck. Could the issue be because my password contains special characters? Such as a equals and a plus sign?

Comment: can you try with driver `--driver com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` param too? - see updates

Comment: also try with passing username and password in connection string it self - see my updated answer

Comment: Get the following error: Could not load db driver class: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver. So I need to setup the driver it seems.

Comment: Yes now download diver jar and place it in sqoop lib dir. Than run sqoop command with `--drive` as shown above. - almost there :)

Answer (score 0):

we have the same issue, once i removed mariadb-java-client-1.4.6.jar and mariadb-java-client-1.2.0.jar from hive lib folder, sqoop commands to mssql working as expected.